# why the supervisor's shutdown brutal_kill mechanism not working as document?

Tags: erlang, shutdown, erlang-supervisor

I wrote a simple application to test the supervisor's shutdown.

https://gist.github.com/zhongwencool/708f8d9ba5ce9553a50a527257482ebb

**Question1:**
Setting `shutdown` to `brutal_kill`, the `supervisor(zoo_sup)` will shutdown the  `gen_server` worker(keeper) immediately without running `zoo_keeper:terminate/2`.
But the test appear to run `zoo_keeper:terminate/2`.

**Question2:**
Setting `shutdown` to `1000ms`, the `supervisor(zoo_sup)` will tell the worker to terminate, but I let the terminate to sleep `3000ms`, as the document, the supervisor will kill the worker when sleep `1000ms`(because I tell the supervisor the shutdown's time only `1000ms`).

But the facts is supervisor just let the worker's `terminate/2` run `3000ms`. why?

See the result here: https://gist.github.com/zhongwencool/708f8d9ba5ce9553a50a527257482ebb

[Erlang's supervisor document](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html)

> `shutdown` defines how a child process must be terminated. `brutal_kill` means that the child process is unconditionally terminated using `exit(Child,kill)`. An integer time-out value means that the supervisor tells the child process to terminate by calling `exit(Child,shutdown)` and then wait for an exit signal with reason shutdown back from the child process. If no exit signal is received within the specified number of milliseconds, the child process is unconditionally terminated using `exit(Child,kill)`.

Comment: Does this `shutdown` even apply when the gen_server crashes itself? I thought it would apply only when the `supervisor` wants to kill a child, when, for example, you call `supervisor:terminate_child/2`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks, you are right, I delete gen_server crash(1=2),
and using supervisor:terminate_child(zoo_sup, keeper), It's woking just fine. :)